# How to get desired color when using bitmap tint multiply?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapimage, tint

I have a bitmap which base color is #EBEBEB, I tint it using multiply mode with color #55AABB and as a result I get #4EAC9D color but I want to have #55AABB as a result color. I've seen that Cout = Csrc * Cdst on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html#MULTIPLY) but I'm not able to get #55AABB as a result. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://colorblendy.com/#!/burn/ebebeb/55aabb) is what is going on. Although it is pretty well explained in the docs. What you need is, I think, DST_IN.

Comment: The image I want to tint contains another colors inside, If I user dst_in they are not shown

Comment: From all the pictures that are shown in the docs what do you want to achieve? If nothing reflects that, can you explain it? From my understanding you just want to retint the whole image with a different color, is correct or am I missing something?

P.S. SRC_ATOP has always done what I needed, so depending on what exactly you are applying to that, this might work.